# Google APIs Explorer posting to remote API instead of local

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm currently developing a (Java) backend for a mobile application using Google App Engine (SDK v1.8.8) and Cloud Endpoints.  I'm using Eclipse (Kepler) with Google Plugin (v3.8.0) to develop/deploy the code.

I've been using Google API's explorer for many months during the development to test the endpoints and up until yesterday, everything was working well...  if I ran App Engine locally, I could test the endpoints at:

`http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer`

Likewise, I could execute against the remotely deployed version at:

`https://1-dot-[my-app-id]-app.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`

...in both cases, everything worked as expected.

However, as of yesterday, local execution no longer works...  instead, my requests are sent to the remote (i.e. live!) version of my API.  I'm still accessing API Explorer on localhost and according to it's output, my requests are still being posted locally...  here is what is printed when I execute a function 'foo' on  'admin' endpoint:

```
 Request
 POST `http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/adminendpoint/v1/foo`
 X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer
```

However, for some reason, these requests are being sent to the live/deployed instance of the API.

I restarted my browser (Chrome) and cleared it's cache, tried another browser (Safari), restarted the machine, re-deployed the API...  It feels like something is being cached somewhere but I'm running out of ideas.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this problem yet? Me and my colleagues have exactly the same problem in our project. In other projects Api Explorer is working just fine. Do you use App Engine Modules as we do?
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

Comment: Hi! Did you noticed the same as I that ApiExplorer started working correctly all of the sudden? For me, it is now working, just that, without touching anywhere in the code which could possible be related to problem.

Comment: No, still no idea what the problem is.  I'm not using modules but I do use a backend for some background tasks...  can't see how that could be related to this issue though.

Comment: @user3159116 are you still experiencing this?

Comment: yes...  no idea how to fix it.  Very annoying.

Comment: Can you use the chrome browser developer tools (CTRL + SHIFT + J) "Network" tab to capture the request and response headers, updating your question with these?

Comment: Also, obviously, don't include the Authorization header's content, just blank it out. You don't want to give out your OAuth bearer token.

Comment: @anonymous4444 I'm having the same problem.  I won't paste the headers here, but the developer tools show that the requests are going to appspot instead of localhost, even though the webpage says they are going to localhost.  Exactly as the original question describes...

Comment: @EllisWhitehead If you want users to help you on SO, you'd do well to provide them the information they ask for. I wouldn't bother to ask you for more info if it was sufficient to just tell me "it doesn't work" or "it sends the requests to the wrong place".

Comment: I'd suggest [opening an issue ticket on the public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry) at this point since it doesn't seem like a case of code error, but rather a potential fix to be made. The googlers there will ask for the same info in all likelihood. The reason headers are requested is because when debugging an HTTP request, this is obviously an important thing to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has been fixed in the Google App Engine SDK for Java version 1.9.17, as indicated in the release notes (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes).  I updated my libraries to 1.9.17, and the APIs explorer started working again for localhost.

Comment: yes, this has solved the issue for me.  Should've tried that but assumed (wrongly) the issue was remote.  Thanks.

Comment: any idea about how to get this working with python sdk